# Is there official clipboard access from office-js for Word add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I have reviewed the [office-js docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office) and not found any formal way of working with the clipboard through a Word add-in.

I attempted to use the newer `navigator.clipboard.writeText` but it is automatically rejected by the internal Word browser (where the add-in is hosted) without prompting the user (like a browser does).  I have not seen any associated support for [permissions policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy) that can be used to communicate with Word that the add-in would like clipboard permissions.

So, I am resorting to the deprecated `document.executeCommand('copy')` for now, but am concerned that will get my add-in rejected by the MS App Store.

Is there an official/sanctioned way to use the clipboard from within a MS Word add-in?

Answer (score 1):

OfficeJS doesn't provide anything for that. You may sill use the  [Document.execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) API which includes "copy", "cut" and "paste". But it was deprecated and may not work in the web browsers any longer.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's one method Range.copyFrom of Excel rich client api. I can't find the alternatives either. Maybe you can ask to provide the new feature. Whether it could be in the future feature list or not may also take some time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The restriction resulting in the console error:

> The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document...

is limited to OfficeJS invoked via the *web browser* but if invoked via a client desktop device like Word on MacOS, the `navigator.clipboard.writeText` appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is super irritating.  See related ticket (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1991) I have had some success with the following workaround.  Seems to work in my current version of chrome - 118.0.5993.70 (Official Build) (arm64)

```
export function navigator_clipboard_writeText(text: string): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    try {
      const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
      textArea.value = text;
      document.body.appendChild(textArea);
      textArea.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      textArea.remove();
      resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}
```